# LLBL Gen Pro 2.6 and Auditing

Tags: database, llblgenpro, auditing

I am using LLBL Gen Pro v2.6 and am attempting to create a means of auditing changes made to the database. Now, I know that LLBL Gen has auditing built into it using AuditorBase and dependency injection. The question I have is; I need to track not only the stuff that LLBL Gen exposes as auditable, but also the User who made the changes. From what I've seen there isn't a built in way of gathering this information. Has anyone used LLBL Gen's built in auditing and determined a way to do this?

Wayne E. Pfeffer

Answer (score 1):

I have used LLBLGens Auditing classes. Determining the user is really something that you will have to handle. There are too many variables for LLBLGen to actually do this for you. How are your users handled? Is this a winforms or asp.net application?

The best solution would be to store the UserId in a session variable or static variable depending on which is more appropriate for your application. In your implementation of the Auditing class you can just pull the UserId from its storage place.

Another potential solution would be to override the Entity Class or the Data Adapter classes and pass the UserId in to your save methods. However, this would be a lot more work.

Answer (score 1):

In my WinForms app, I accomplish this by creating a custom IPrincipal and stick that on System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal when a user logs into the application.  Then, I can easily grab that from inside my LLBLGen auditing classes.

Answer (score 0):

We're also about to implement auditing of changes to the db, and have the same issue of adding the user_id to the auditlog. I can see you can do the pull-approach, e.g. fetchingn the user_id from the web session (we're building a web application), but this would completely mess up the layering of the application, as I see it!?

I.e. if the DAL pulls data information from the presentation layer (web session), I won't be able to use the DAL in other contexts?

Best regards,

--thomas